# Why is $ F_{|x|}(x) \equiv F_{x}(x)-F_{x}(-x) $?

Tags: probability

I don't fully understand the jump from

$\quad F_{|X|}(x)= Pr[-x \leq X \leq x]$

to

$\quad F_{|x|}(x) \equiv F_{x}(x)-F_{x}(-x) \quad$

maybe someone can give an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F(x)=P(X\leq x )$ we have that
$$P(-x\leq X\leq x)=F(x)-F(-x)$$

Comment: I still don't intuitively understand this <.<

Comment: The probability of $X$ being less than $a$ is the value of function in $a$. Now We wont the acumulated probability between  $a$ an $b$ so we take te acumulated till a less the acumulated till b, thats it, the difference of the values of the function in that points